# Selecting records based on current time falling between ProgramStart and ProgramEnd

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to select all records from my SQL Server database that falls between a certain hour.  Let me give you an example:

Current time is 9:33 am and you have numerous Program records in the database that have an ProgramStart and ProgramEnd.  An example of the dates might be:

```
 | ProgramStart             | ProgramEnd              | ClientID |
 +--------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
 | 1900-01-01 09:00:00.000  | 1900-01-01 10:00:00.000 | 5        |
 +--------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
 | 1900-01-01 11:00:00.000  | 1900-01-01 13:00:00.000 | 4        |
 +--------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
 | 1900-01-01 12:00:00.000  | 1900-01-01 14:00:00.000 | 5        |
 +--------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
 | 1900-01-01 11:00:00.000  | 1900-01-01 13:00:00.000 | 6        |
 +--------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
 | 1900-01-01 16:00:00.000  | 1900-01-01 17:00:00.000 | 7        |
 +--------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
 | 1900-01-01 16:00:00.000  | 1900-01-01 17:00:00.000 | 5        |
 +--------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
 | 1900-01-01 17:00:00.000  | 1900-01-01 18:00:00.000 | 4        |
 +--------------------------+-------------------------+----------+
```

I want to extract all records for client 5 and between the current time which is 9:33am

How does one do that with SQL.  I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
 SELECT CAST('1900-01-01 09:33:00.000' AS datetime) AS TimeNow, * FROM Programs
 WHERE ClientID = 5
 AND TimeNow BETWEEN '1900-01-01 09:00:00.000' AND '1900-01-01 10:00:00.000'
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
    from Programs
    where ClientId = 5
        and DATEADD(Day, 0-DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GetDate()), GetDate()) between ProgramStart and ProgramEnd
```

Answer (score 2):

This but will remove the date component from GETDATE:

```
DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
```

Plugging this into the query

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
     Programs
WHERE
     ClientID = 5
     AND
     DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), GETDATE())
                 BETWEEN ProgramStart AND ProgramEnd
```

On SQL Server 2008+ you have the time datatype too. However, the triple CAST one would invalidate indexes on ProgramStart and ProgramEnd so it'd worth playing with something like the 2nd one

```
CAST(GETDATE() AS time) BETWEEN CAST(ProgramStart AS time) AND CAST(ProgramEnd AS time)
CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS time) AS smalldatetime) BETWEEN ProgramStart AND ProgramEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM Programs
WHERE ClientId = 5
AND GETDATE() BETWEEN ProgramStart AND ProgramEnd
```

**Update**
I didn't notice the lack of a date component in the data.  You should look at gbn's answer to scrape the date out after calling GetDate().  I won't just copy his code here because that seems wrong.  :)

Comment: -1. How can `03 Nov 2010 20:10.xx.yyyy` *ever* be between `1900-01-01 09:00:00.000` and `1900-01-01 10:00:00.000`? Edit: -1 removed.

Comment: Yep, didn't notice that until I saw other answers.